# Add object in mongodb through yeoman generator-angular-fullstack

Tags: mongodb, yeoman, mean-stack, yeoman-generator

I'm using yeoman generator-angular-fullstack to deploy a new project.

I'm looking for a way to add an object to my MongoDB but I can't find if there is a proper command through yo.

Is there one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself the answer. To add object in model schema type in cmd

> angular-fullstack:endpoint nameOfModel